# LexikJWTAuthentication : custom exception on empty fields

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I use LexikJWTAuthentication on a symfony project. The authenticattion work perfectly but I want to customize the exception when no email or password are given in my request.

I found this in the Lexik [documentation](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/3.x/Resources/doc/2-data-customization.rst) to customize the exception when authentication fail but is there a way to customize the exception when empty fields are provided ?

[image: Login request on Postman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can achieve that with Lexik, if no email/password are provided, you got a BAD Request and Lexik can do nothing for you.
But Symfony can help you as described in [Events and Event Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) and [Built-in Symfony Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html)

this is a example that work for me in both SF 5 and 6 :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class RequestListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => [
                ['onKernelException']
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelException(RequestEvent $event) {
        dd($throwable = $event->getThrowable());
    }
}
```

$throwable now contain any Exception that can happen in you app, you can check instance of or status codeand implement your own logic there.

in some project, I redirect user to home page instead of 404 error page like that :

```
if($throwable instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
    $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('home_page'));
    $event->setResponse($response)
}
```

So that in your case you can do

```
if ($throwable instanceof BadRequestHttpException) {
    $event->setResponse(new Response("Mail is required"));
}
```

But I don't think is a good solution to do that, because in you case is not the fault of your customer to not having body on request but of the developper , the real case you must check is

```
{
"email" : "",
"password" : ""   
}
```

And here we got HTTP 401 invalid credential and here your customer must give email/password combination.

Comment: Works perfectly for my case, I didn't use EventListeners on my project so 'I'll take a look on it. Thanks !